# I am unable to access a nested array of documents in a mongodb collection

Tags: arrays, mongodb, nested, document

I have a collection in MongoDB that includes a field that is an array of documents.  I need to access each of the fields in the documents and have been unable to make it work.

I have a collection called transactions.  Here is an example of the data in the collection:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cb02d3c65a86045bc690d43"), "InvoiceNo" : 536366, "Customer_ID" : 17850, "Date" : 40513, "Planet" : "Abydos", "Purchase" : "[{'ItemNo': 22633, 'UnitPrice': 1.85, 'Description': u'BRAWNDO', 'Quantity': 6}, {'ItemNo': 22632, 'UnitPrice': 1.85, 'Description': u'HAND WARMER RED POLKA DOT', 'Quantity': 6}]" }
```

I am trying to access the fields within the Purchase array.

This is one invoice in the transactions collection.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cb02d3c65a86045bc690d43"), "InvoiceNo" : 536366, "Customer_ID" : 17850, "Date" : 40513, "Planet" : "Abydos", "Purchase" : "[{'ItemNo': 22633, 'UnitPrice': 1.85, 'Description': u'BRAWNDO', 'Quantity': 6}, {'ItemNo': 22632, 'UnitPrice': 1.85, 'Description': u'HAND WARMER RED POLKA DOT', 'Quantity': 6}]" }
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
db.transactions.find( {"Purchase":{"ItemNo":"22633"}})
db.transactions.find( {"Purchase":{"UnitPrice":1.85}})
db.transactions.find({'Purchase.Quantity':{$lt:37}})
db.transactions.find({'Purchase.UnitPrice':{$lte:3.82}})
db.transactions.find({'Purchase.UnitPrice':{$elemMatch:{$in:1.85}}})
```

I would expect the above queries to return data since I am querying data that I see in the transactions collection.  The code runs but does not return data.

Comment: The query `db.transactions.find({ "Purchase.ItemNo" : 22633 })` should return data. Can you try that? Note that your first query is filtering on text ("22633") instead of a numerical value (22633).

Comment: Thanks Adam, but when I try this query I get no data.  I can query at the top level but not within the Purchase array.

Comment: I just noticed that ItemNo is a unicode string.  I tried querying it with quotes but still no data.